# Phalcon validation - how to display only the first error message per field

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Please don't recommend 'cancelOnFail' because it doesn't work properly if I'm validating more than one field

```
    $this->add(
        'email',
        new PresenceOf(
            [
                'message' => 'The e-mail is required',
            ]
        )
    );

    $this->add(
        'email',
        new Email(
            [
                'message' => 'The e-mail is not valid',
            ]
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only display first error message, you should write like this.

```
$messages->current()->getMessage()
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, but that will only work if I've one field in my validation rules, I've multiple fields, 1. email, 2. password 3. first_name, etc